# CakePHP Select Box Value Not Right After Order By

Tags: php, cakephp

```
//My Owner Model
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Owner' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'owner',
    ),
);

//My Tickets Controller

//Find the owners of the ticket to build select box
$owners = $this->Ticket->Owner->find('list', array(
         'fields' => array('Owner.id', 'Owner.username')
         'order' => array('Owner.username' => 'asc')
));

//Add "All" to the array of owners at 0 (no owner ids are 0)
array_splice($owners, 0, 0, "All");
//Set owner variable in my view.
$this->set(compact('owners'));

//My template file or view
echo $this->Form->create('Ticket', array(
    'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'find'), $this->params['pass'])));
    echo $this->Form->input('title', array('div' => false));
    echo "<br /><br />";
            //Build the selectbox ordered by username
    echo $this->Form->input('owner', array('div' => false, 'options' => $owners, 'id' => 'EndUser'));
    echo "<br /><br />";
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

When the select box is built the select box is sorted by username like I would like - but their ids do not switch with the username.

If I do a `print_r($owners)` before the `array_splice($owners, 0, 0, "All");` the array is correct.  When i `print_r($owners)` after the `array_splice($owners, 0, 0, "All");` the array is incorrect - but I don't know why... I am assuming `array_splice` renumbers the array...  How could add "Any" to the array without messing up my relationships?

Comment: I figured it out - but can't answer my own question. Apparently you can just add arrays - who knew! (I am sure probably most all of you!
//Add All to top of array
$allarray=array( 0 => "All");
$owners = $allarray + $owners;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd best use the `empty` option of the input method of the Form helper. You can pass along a key to go with it, so change:

```
echo $this->Form->input('owner', array('div' => false, 'options' => $owners, 'id' => 'EndUser'));
```

To this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('owner', array(
    'div' => false,
    'options' => $owners,
    'empty' => array(0 => 'All'), // Add this line
    'id' => 'EndUser'
));
```

Comment: Awesome - that is even better! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$owners = $this->Ticket->Owner->find('list', array(
         'conditions' => array('Owner.id NOT'=>'0')
         'fields' => array('Owner.id', 'Owner.username')
         'order' => array('Owner.username' => 'asc')
));
```